# Edittext worked as searchview by post the search api with some params

Tags: android

I used EditText instead of SearchView. But here the problem is different I used to search in ListView and data in the ListView is coming when I hit the search api..let me explain..
Actually I have an api the when I put char in EditText , I get that char from EditText and hit the api in postman by passing the parameters in body, two params I have passed("key"=the char i get from EditText, user_id=null).
And I want to search the data like when I press "m" then "m" will post as value of "key" and shows the data , at the same time if i press "mo" then the api again hits at the same time and get me the results in ListView 
Please help me...

```
 mSearchFriends.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            String input;
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                input = String.valueOf(mSearchFriends.getText());
                new PostSearchApi(Add.this) {
                    @Override
                    public void fetchData(String output) {
                        Log.d("response>>>>>",output);
                        //input = String.valueOf(mSearchFriends.getText());
                        rowItemListForSearchList = new ArrayList<>();
                        mSearchListAdapter = new SearchListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),rowItemListForSearchList);
                        getjsonOfContact(output);
                        lvContacts.setAdapter(mSearchListAdapter);
                        mSearchListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mTextView_No_Result_Found.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }.execute(input,"");
```

It shows me result but after pressing the the arrow button on phone keyboard. What I want is I want to search random data when I type a character. I also tried the code in OnTextChanged method but when I type "a" then api hits and takes time when it completed then only i can type other character..

But the necessity is the functionality like finding the friends on facebook

Comment: put your code here

Answer (score 1):

Since no code provided by you, as far as I understand your ques,  you can get realtime text changing events from `EditText` like this:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             //on Text change event. s is the text that is entered
            // put your code here. Make a hit to your api and pass `s` as  your parameter.
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: you are using setOnEditorActionListener @I.d007 as you posted now . Try this

Comment: I updated my ques.. Yes I tried it but api hits every time when putting character in edittext. It should be when I put second character then first api stops and updates the latest data and then hit api with new data at the same time @KarandeepAtwal